# event on command executed

Tags: autocmd

I want to run a command when I change the textwidth.
I have tried
     autocmd CmdlineLeave * call Myfunction()

When I do `:set tw=40`, the function is called before tw is changed.

What is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's `OptionSet` autocommand. For example,

```
augroup test | au!
    autocmd OptionSet textwidth call NewTextWidth(v:option_type, v:option_new)
augroup end

function! NewTextWidth(type, value)
    echom 'set' a:type 'textwidth' a:value
endfunction
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need